# Why won't my sprite/entity move in a straight line?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, game-engine, impactjs

My entity is supposed to move in straight line toward the mouse. It's close, but not quite there yet. Here's a [working demo](http://www.3110.a.hostable.me/~a3110hos/asteroids/baked.html) to show you what I mean.

And here's a screenshot:
[image: Entity not moving in a straight line.]
The red represents the path the mouse took. As you can see, the entity does not take the same path.

Relevant code:

```
EntityPlayer = ig.Entity.extend({

    movementspeed: 400,

    update: function() {
        this.parent();
        this.move_toward_coord(ig.input.mouse.x, ig.input.mouse.y);
    },

    move_toward_coord: function(x, y) {
        var distance_to_target_x = x - this.pos.x - this.size.x / 2;
        var distance_to_target_y = y - this.pos.y - this.size.y / 2;
        if(Math.abs(distance_to_target_x) > 1 || Math.abs(distance_to_target_y) > 1) {
            this.vel.x = (distance_to_target_x > 1 ? 1 : -1) * this.movementspeed * (Math.abs(distance_to_target_x) / (Math.abs(distance_to_target_x) + Math.abs(distance_to_target_y)));
            this.vel.y = (distance_to_target_y > 1 ? 1 : -1) * this.movementspeed * (Math.abs(distance_to_target_y) / (Math.abs(distance_to_target_x) + Math.abs(distance_to_target_y)));
        } else {
            this.vel.y = 0;
            this.vel.x = 0;
        }
    }

});
```

I suspect there is something wrong with the `move_to_coord` method, but after tweaking for too many hours, I'm still not sure what it is...

Why doesn't the ship travel in a straight line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ughh!! I figured it out literally seconds after I posted this. Sorry, my bad. It was because of a property called `maxVel` which was limiting the speed on either the `x` or `y` velocity, sometimes one more than the other. >.<

Comment: A pretty picture, some concise code, and a solution! win win win. +1 +1 Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Indeed, you could turn this into a tutorial on how to make your spaceship do pretty curving paths...

Comment: @PhilH I agree.  The behavior you were getting is much more interesting than the desired behavior! :)

Comment: @CamFred It's interesting, yes. But it's unpredictable. If the entity is "set" to move at a speed of 400 pixels per second, he wouldn't actually move at that speed. Later, there will be "path curving" to make cornering seem more realistic, but for now it's great that it travels at the correct rate. =)